# convert ascii characters to ruby encoding

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm testing a feature with watir and running into an issue with validating ascii characters in the html.

I'm grabbing the product description from a database like so 'Company&*reg*; Some Product' and use it as the string that i'm validating against.

and it shows up that way in the html. However Ruby is looking for Company\u00AE Some Product, so my test is failing.

Anyone have any solutions for getting around these special characters when they turn up?

Comment: Unicode 00AE is the "registered" (r inside a circle) symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Entities gem may help:

http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/

http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/doc/

Comment: There seems to be a mix of named (&reg;) and decimal (&#226) in the data I'm drawing from. Using .decode seems to work for named, but it gets a different unicode value for the symbol. in rib : Staples\u00AE Cushing\u2122 Luxura\u00AE Manager's Chair, Black
using .decode Staples\u00AE Cushing\u0099 Luxura\u00AE Manager's Chair, Black

Comment: You may have to use the existing code as a start and add to it. If you're lucky, doing a decode followed by encode may normalize things.